# Problem with resizing angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have angular material table, and component for resizing columns in there. Problem is that when I want to resize column to right, columns left from the column I'm resizing are shrinking down. I want every column to stay same width, only the one that I'm resizing I want to have minimal width of 20px lets say, and maximum is infinite for now, as long as user is moving mouse. How can i prevent columns that are not resizing, to resize. Columns on right are working pretty good, but left from column I'm resizing have strange behavior.

```
<div class="view-body">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort #tableRef>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index" matColumnDef="{{column.field}}">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [class]="'mat-column-'+ column.field">
        <div style="width: 80%" mat-sort-header>
          {{globalVariables?.texts?.labels[column.field]}}
          <ng-container *ngIf="column.field==='category'">
            <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="categoryMenu" aria-label="Icon-button with a menu">
              <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </ng-container>

        </div>
        <span class="resize-handle" (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, column.id)" *ngIf="i!=0"></span>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, i, row.category)">
        <div class="column-content" [ngSwitch]="column.id">
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="0"><textarea disabled matInput class='textarea'>{{row.gid}} </textarea>
          </ng-container>
          <textarea disabled class="textarea" matInput *ngSwitchCase="1">{{row.category}}</textarea>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="2"><textarea matInput class='textarea'
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 2">{{row.serialKey}}</textarea>
            <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 2)"
              value={{row.serialKey}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)">
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="3"><textarea class='textarea' matInput disabled
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 3">{{row.producer}}</textarea>
            <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 3)"
              value={{row.producer}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)"
              list="itemProducer">
            <datalist id="itemProducer">
              <option *ngFor="let producer of globalVariables.dataLists.producer" value={{producer}}> {{producer}}
              </option>
            </datalist>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="4">
            <textarea disabled class="textarea" matInput disabled
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 4">{{row.model}}
            </textarea>
            <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 4)"
              value={{row.model}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)" list="itemModels">
            <datalist id="itemModels">
              <option *ngFor="let model of globalVariables.dataLists.model" value={{model}}> {{model}} </option>
            </datalist>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="5"> <textarea disabled matInput class='textarea'
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 5">{{row.type}}
          </textarea>
            <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 5)"
              value={{row.type}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)" list="itemTypes">
            <datalist id="itemTypes">
              <option *ngFor="let type of globalVariables.dataLists.types" value={{type}}> {{type}} </option>
            </datalist>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="6"><textarea disabled class="textarea" matInput
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 6">{{row.location}}
            </textarea>
            <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 6)"
              value={{row.location}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)"
              list="itemLocation">
            <datalist id="itemLocation">
              <option *ngFor="let local of globalVariables.dataLists.location" value={{local}}> {{local}} </option>
            </datalist>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="7"> <textarea disabled class="textarea" matInput
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 7">{{row.count}}
            </textarea>
            <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 7)"
              value={{row.count}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)">
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="8"> <textarea disabled class="textarea" matInput
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 8">{{row.notes}} </textarea>
            <textarea matInput disabled
              *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 8)"
              value={{row.notes}} class="textarea" onfocus="this.select()" #inSK
              (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)"></textarea>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="9"> <textarea class="textarea" matInput disabled
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 9">{{row.purchased
              |
              date}} </textarea>
            <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 9)"
              value={{row.purchased}} onfocus="this.select()" type="date" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)">
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="10"><a
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 10">
              <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="leased" *ngIf="row.leased">check_circle_outline</mat-icon>
            </a>
            <mat-checkbox *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 10)"
              [ngModel]="row.leased" (change)="valueChange(!row.leased)"></mat-checkbox>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="11">
            <textarea class="textarea" matInput disabled
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 11">
              {{row.leased ? (row.leasingUntil | date) : ''}}
            </textarea>
            <input matInput
              *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 11)"
              value={{row.leasingUntil}} onfocus="this.select()" type="date" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)">
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="12"><textarea disabled class="textarea" matInput
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 12">{{row.serviceUntil
              | date}} </textarea>
            <input matInput
              *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 13)"
              value={{row.serviceUntil}} onfocus="this.select()" type="date" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)">
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="13"> <textarea disabled class="textarea" matInput
              *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 13">{{row.pc}}
          </textarea>
            <input matInput
              *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 13)"
              value={{row.pc}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)" list="itemPCRel">
            <datalist id="itemPCRel">
              <option *ngFor="let rel of globalVariables.dataLists.pcRel" value={{rel}}> {{rel}} </option>
            </datalist>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </td>

    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    <tr *matNoDataRow>
      <td colspan="14">{{globalVariables.texts.phrases.noMatchingData}} "{{input.value}}" in
        "{{globalVariables.selectedCategory}}"</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

```
.mat-sort-header {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mat-sort-header-container {
  min-width: 2rem !important;
  height: 100% !important;

  margin: 0 auto !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mat-sort-header:hover .mat-sort-header-arrow {
  color: white !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}


.mat-table {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

th.mat-header-cell:last-of-type,
td.mat-cell:last-of-type,
td.mat-footer-cell:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

th.mat-header-cell,
td.mat-cell,
td.mat-footer-cell {
  height: 2rem !important;
}
.column-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.view-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 80vh;

  min-width: 99.5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

th {
  background-color: $color-corporate-design-main;
  color: $color-light;
}

td {
  &:hover {
    background-color: $color-corporate-design-main-80;
    color: $color-light;
  }
}

tr {
  &:hover {
    background-color: $color-corporate-design-main-60;
    color: $color-light;
  }
}

.notes {
  max-height: 2em;

  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.context-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}

.textarea {
  color: $color-dark;
}

.context-edit {
  color: $color-corporate-design-main;
}

.context-delete {
  color: $color-alert;
}

.ina-progress-bar {
  width: 95.5%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 0.25%;
  margin-bottom: -2em;
  padding-top: 2em;
  color: $color-corporate-design-accent-1;
}

.menue-typography {
  font-family: $typo-sub;
}

.mat-icon-button {
  width: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

table th {
  position: relative;
  border-right: 2px solid lightgrey;
}

.resize-handle {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 10px solid lightgray;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: col-resize;
  opacity: 0;
}

.resize-handle:hover {
  width: 30px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow {
  color: white; /*change color of arrow*/
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I was mainly trying to make somehow table not to resize to left at all, but it constantly goes left, and when there is not enough space on left, it start resizing to right. I know that code is not clean, but I'm new to Angular, and Im working on someone else project, and I'm only adding functions in components, no directives or something like that.

```
 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<Item>;
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger, { static: true }) matMenuTrigger: any;
  @ViewChild(MatTable, { read: ElementRef }) private matTableRef: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild(CdkDrag) draggableElement!: CdkDrag;
  @HostListener('window:resize')
  globalVariables = GLOBAL_VARIABLES;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Item> = new MatTableDataSource();
  menuTopLeftPosition = { x: '0', y: '0' };
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];
  columns: any[] = [
    { field: 'gid', width: 5, id: 0 },
    { field: 'category', width: 5, id: 1 },
    { field: 'serialKey', width: 5, id: 2 },
    { field: 'producer', width: 5, id: 3 },
    { field: 'model', width: 5, id: 4 },
    { field: 'type', width: 5, id: 5 },
    { field: 'location', width: 5, id: 6 },
    { field: 'count', width: 5, id: 7 },
    { field: 'notes', width: 5, id: 8 },
    { field: 'purchased', width: 5, id: 9 },
    { field: 'leased', width: 5, id: 10 },
    { field: 'leasingUntil', width: 5, id: 11 },
    { field: 'serviceUntil', width: 5, id: 12 },
    { field: 'pcRel', width: 5, id: 13 },
  ];

  deleteFlag = false;
  inputFallBack =
    'diesistnureindummerstringdenkeinusersoindenfiltereingebenwuerde';
  model: string;
  loading: boolean;
  modelChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  pressed = false;
  currentResizeIndex: number;
  startX: number;
  startWidth: number;
  isResizingRight: boolean;
  resizableMousemove: () => void;
  resizableMouseup: () => void;
  constructor(
    private apiService: InaApiService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private router: Router,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.initialLoading();
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.myPredicate();
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.globalVariables.selectedCategory =
      this.globalVariables.texts.categoryAll;
    this.setDisplayedColumns();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.setTableResize(this.matTableRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
  }

  initialLoading(): void {
    this.deleteFlag = false;

    if (this.globalVariables.allowed) {
      this.updateDataLists();
    }
    this.updateDataSource();
  }

  setTableResize(tableWidth: number) {
    let totWidth = 0;
    this.columns.forEach((column) => {
      totWidth += column.width;
    });
    const scale = tableWidth / totWidth;
    console.log(tableWidth);
    this.columns.forEach((column) => {
      console.log(column.width);
      column.width = column.width * scale - 30;

      this.setColumnWidth(column);
    });
  }
  private checkResizing(event, index) {
    const cellData = this.getCellData(index);
    if (
      index === 0 ||
      (Math.abs(event.pageX - cellData.right) < cellData.width / 2 &&
        index !== this.columns.length - 1)
    ) {
      this.isResizingRight = true;
    } else {
      this.isResizingRight = false;
    }
  }
  onResizeColumn(event: any, index: number) {
    this.checkResizing(event, index);
    this.currentResizeIndex = index;
    this.pressed = true;
    this.startX = event.pageX;
    this.startWidth = event.target.parentElement.clientWidth;

    event.preventDefault();
    this.mouseMove(index);
    const mouseUpListener = this.renderer.listen('document', 'mouseup', () => {
      this.pressed = false;
      this.resizableMousemove();

      mouseUpListener();
    });
  }
  private getCellData(index: number) {
    const headerRow =
      this.matTableRef.nativeElement.children[0].querySelector('tr');
    const cell = headerRow.children[index];
    console.log(cell);
    return cell.getBoundingClientRect();
  }

  mouseMove(index: number) {
    this.resizableMousemove = this.renderer.listen(
      'document',
      'mousemove',
      (event) => {
        if (this.pressed && event.buttons) {
          let dx: number;
          console.log(event.pageX, this.startX);

          if (index === 13) {
            dx = this.isResizingRight
              ? -event.pageX + this.startX // Swap calculation for dx
              : event.pageX - this.startX; // Swap calculation for dx
          } else {
            dx = this.isResizingRight
              ? event.pageX - this.startX
              : -event.pageX + this.startX;
          }

          const width = this.startWidth + dx;
          console.log(dx, this.currentResizeIndex, index, width);
          if (this.currentResizeIndex === index && width > 50) {
            this.columns[index].width = width;
            this.setColumnWidth(this.columns[index]);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }

  setColumnWidthChanges(index: number, width: number) {
    const orgWidth = this.columns[index].width;
    const dx = width - orgWidth;
    if (dx !== 0) {
      const newWidth = width < 20 ? 20 : width; // check if new width is less than 5px
      this.columns[index].width = newWidth;
      this.setColumnWidth(this.columns[index]);
      console.log(newWidth);
      if (newWidth === 20) {
        // reset start position and width
        this.startX = this.startX - (orgWidth - 20);
        this.startWidth = 20;
      }
    }
  }
  setColumnWidth(column: any) {
    const columnEls = Array.from(
      document.getElementsByClassName('mat-column-' + column.field)
    );
    columnEls.forEach((el: HTMLDivElement) => {
      el.style.minWidth = column.width + 'px';
    });
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  setDisplayedColumns() {
    this.columns.forEach((column, index) => {
     column.index = index;
      this.displayedColumns[index] = column.field;
    });
  }
```